# how to resolve the execute taskAction :app:mergeDebugResources in android studio 3.2

Tags: android, sql-server

```
enter code herebuild failed 3 s 572 ms
```

Run build   3 s 383 ms
Load build  7 ms
Configure build 186 ms
Calculate task graph    29 ms
Run tasks   3 s 153 ms
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader   23 ms
:app:checkDebugClasspath    238 ms
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild  37 ms
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript   16 ms
:app:checkDebugManifest 3 ms
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig   4 ms
:app:prepareLintJar 9 ms
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug    2 ms
:app:generateDebugResValues 2 ms
:app:generateDebugResources 1 ms
:app:mergeDebugResources    2 s 783 ms
Execute taskAction  2 s 331 ms
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug    12 ms

error

Android resource compilation failed
Output:  E:\Developer Data\Sehr Cool Apps\Sehr Cool Apps Projects\MadaniQaidahPro\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2179: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\Zahra University.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\8fa4b1c90c8de9038085ac11ac8d4499\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        E:\Developer Data\Sehr Cool Apps\Sehr Cool Apps Projects\MadaniQaidahPro\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        E:\Developer Data\Sehr Cool Apps\Sehr Cool Apps Projects\MadaniQaidahPro\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Answer (score 0):

Check your files under res/values/. One of them will be defining an "id" resource (probably `<item type="id" name="...">...</item>`) and it will have some value in it. ID resources can either have **no** value or reference another ID resource. Fix these resources in your values files and you should be fine.

Another option is that the broken resource is coming from one of your dependencies. In that case check what is the name of the resource in `E:\Developer Data\Sehr Cool Apps\Sehr Cool Apps Projects\MadaniQaidahPro\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2179` and try to find where it's coming from.